# Python - Some parts of array ignored? Why? Fix?

Tags: python, macos

I've started to make an AI in python, and a little BASh commands with os.system (I'm using a Mac!). The AI works from a command similar to:

```
if uInput.upper() in uiArray:
            tmp = choice(aiArray)
            system("say -i " + str(tmp))
```

Choice is `import`ed `from random`. `say -i` is a command built into the Mac shell which reads text aloud. It worked fine until I made the `uiQuoteAsk` array. It mostly works, but it ignores the 
`"PLEASE TELL ME QUOTE",
"PLEASE TELL QUOTE"`, `"QUOTE"`, and `"GIVE ME A QUOTE"` parts. If I run my AI, nothing will happen when these four phrases are typed. How can I fix this and why is it doing this? 
Here is my code:

```
# coding: utf-8
# TANGIS-V, the Text-based Artificial Next-Gen Intelligence Sys with Voice
# Programmed by Keegan Kuhn
# 
# Update info:
# v0: Creation, 1.18.17
# v0.1: Main structure built, 1.18.17
# v0.1.1: Content added to user and AI greetings, 1.19.17
# v0.1.1.1: Added greeting to main function, 1.19.17
# v0.1.1.2: Added user input to main function, 1.19.17
# v0.1.2: Changed 'input' to 'raw_input' & added 1st AI reply, 1.20.17
# v0.1.3: Main functon into loop & added AI greeting before 'main()', 1.20.17
# v0.1.3.1: uiNameAsk array added, 1.20.17
# v0.1.3.1.1: Content added to uiNameAsk array, 1.20.17
# v0.2: 'system' now imports from 'os', 1.20.17
# v0.2.1: Added some more arrays and replies, 1.20.17
# v0.3: Added voice, 1.23.17
# v0.3.1: Added math mod, 10.23.17
# v0.3.1.1: Enables user to perform math functions, 1.25.17
# v0.3.1.2: Adds voice to beginning, 1.25,17

###################################################
#                  VVV  MAIN VVV                  #
###################################################

# Main
def main():
    tmp = "null"
    uInput = raw_input(">>> ")
    if uInput.upper() in uiGreetings:
        tmp = choice(aiGreetings)
        system("say -i " + str(tmp))
    #
    #
    #
    if uInput.upper() in uiNameAsk:
        tmp = choice(aiNameAnswer) 
        system("say -i " + str(tmp))
    #
    #
    #
    if uInput.upper() in uiClear:
        system("clear")
    #
    #
    #
    if uInput.upper() in uiJokeAsk:
        tmp = choice(aiJoke)
        system("say -i " + str(tmp))
    #
    #
    #
    if uInput.upper() in uiMath:
        system("say -i Read the text below for math help.")
        print "############################################"
        print "'+' for addition"
        print "'-' for subtraction"
        print "'*' for multiplication"
        print "'** for exponents"
        print "'/' for division"
        print "And '.' for decimals"
        print "Find sqrt by typing 'sqrt()' and putting the number in parenthesis."
        print "Type 'pi' or 'phi' in equation to easily get its value."
        print "############################################"
        print
        tmp = eval(raw_input("Type your math problem >>> "))
        system("say -i The answer is " + str(tmp) + ".")
        system("say -i Quitting math interface.")
    #
    #
    #
    if uInput.upper() in uiQuoteAsk:
        tmp = choice(aiQuote)
                system("say -i " + str(tmp))
    #
    #
    #
    main()

###################################################
#                  ^^^  MAIN ^^^                  #
###################################################



###################################################
###################################################



###################################################
#                  VVV  INIT VVV                  #
###################################################

# Init
print "[ ] Starting TANGIS ..."
#
#
# Init, mod import
from random import choice
from os import system
from math import sqrt
#
#
# Init, array setup
#
# Init, user-input array setup 
uiGreetings = [
    "HI",
    "HEY",
    "HELLO",
    "HOWDY",
    "GOOD DAY",
    "GOOD MORNING",
    "MORNING",
    "GOOD AFTERNOON",
    "AFTERNOON",
    "GOOD EVENING",
    "GOOD EVE",
    "EVENING",
    "EVE",
    "YO",
    "WHATS UP",
    "WHATSUP",
    "SUP"
    ]

uiNameAsk = [
    "WHAT IS YOUR NAME",
    "WHATS YOUR NAME",
    "WHAT ARE YOU CALLED",
    "WHAT ARE YOU NAMED",
    "WHATRE YOU NAMED",
    "WHATRE YOU CALLED"
]

uiClear = [
    "CLEAR",
    "CLS",
    "CLEAR THE SCREEN",
    "CLEAR SCREEN",
    "CLEARSCREEN",
    "CLEAN",
    "CLEAN THE SCREEN",
    "CLEAN SCREEN",
    "CLEANSCREEN",
    "WIPE",
    "WIPE THE SCEEN",
    "WIPE SCREEN",
    "WIPESCREEN",
    "SCREEN CLEAR",
    "SCREENCLEAR",
    "SCREEN CLEAN",
    "SCREENCLEAN",
    "SCREEN WIPE",
    "SCREENWIPE"
]

uiJokeAsk = [
    "CAN YOU TELL ME A JOKE",
    "TELL ME A JOKE",
    "CAN YOU TELL JOKE",
    "TELL JOKE",
    "CAN YOU JOKE",
    "JOKE",
    "CAN YOU SAY A JOKE",
    "SAY A JOKE",
    "SAY SOMETHING FUNNY",
    "TELL ME SOMETHING FUNNY",
    "TELL SOMETHING FUNNY",
    "FUNNY" ,
    "ANOTHER JOKE",
    "TELL ME ANOTHER JOKE",
    "CAN TELL ME ANOTHER JOKE"
]

uiMath = [
    "MATH",
    "DO MATH",
    "CAN YOU DO MATH",
    "MATHEMATICS",
    "DO MATHEMATICS",
    "CAN YOU DO MATHEMATICS",
    "MATHEMATIC",
        "DO MATHEMATIC",
        "CAN YOU DO MATHEMATIC",
    "MATHS",
        "DO MATHS",
        "CAN YOU DO MATHS",
    "LETS DO MATH",
    "LETS DO SOME MATH"
]

uiQuoteAsk = [
    "CAN YOU TELL ME A QUOTE",
        "CAN YOU TELL ME QUOTE",
        "CAN YOU TELL QUOTE",
    "CAN YOU PLEASE TELL ME A QUOTE",
    "CAN YOU PLEASE TELL ME QUOTE",
    "CAN YOU PLEASE TELL QUOTE",
    "PLEASE TELL ME A QUOTE",
    "PLEASE TELL ME QUOTE"
        "PLEASE TELL QUOTE",
    "TELL A QUOTE",
    "CAN YOU TELL A QUOTE",
        "CAN YOU PLEASE TELL A QUOTE",
        "PLEASE TELL A QUOTE",
    "TELL ME A QUOTE"
    "QUOTE",
    "GIVE ME A QUOTE",
    "TELL ME A QUOTE"
]

#
#
# Init, AI array setup
aiGreetings = [
    "Greetings.",
    "Welcome.",
    "Hello.",
    "Good day."
    ]

aiNameAnswer = [
    "I am known as TANGIS-V.",
    "I am known as TANGIS-V, the Text-based Artificial Next-Gen Intelligence Sys with Voice.",
    "I am called TANGIS-V.",
    "I am TANGIS-V.",
    "I am TANGIS-V, the Text-based Artificial Next-Gen Intelligence Sys.",
    "I am known as TANGIS-V, the Text-based Artificial Next-Generation Intelligence System with Voice.",
    "I am TANGIS-V, the Text-based Artificial Next-Generation Intelligence System with Voice."
]

aiJoke = [

    'How did the programmer die in the shower? Because he read the shampoo bottle instructions: Lather. Rinse. Repeat.',

    'Two strings walk into a bar and sit down. The bartender says, “So what’ll it be?” The first string says, “I think I’ll have a beer quag fulk boorg jdk^CjfdLk jk3s d#f67howe%^U r89nvy~~owmc63^wmc63^Dz x.xvcu.” “Please excuse my friend,” the second string says, “He isn’t null-terminated.”'

]

aiQuote = [
    "Give a fish to a boy, give him a meal for a day. Teach a boy to fish, give him a meal for a lifetime. - Unknown",
    "Do not ask what your country can do for you, ask what you can do for your country. - John F. Kennedy"
]

#
#
# Init, misc vars
ver = "0.3.1"
tmp = 0
pi = 3.14
phi = 1.68

print "[*] TANGIS started !"

system("say -i " + str(choice(aiGreetings)) )

main()

###################################################
#                  ^^^  INIT ^^^                  #
###################################################
```

Comment: You're missing at least two commas, which you might have noticed if you used consistent formatting.

Comment: Like @JaredSmith said, you missed 2 commas on yours `uiQuoteAsk` list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is merging two strings together because you're missing a comma:

Here is a snippet of your code:

```
"PLEASE TELL ME A QUOTE",
"PLEASE TELL ME QUOTE"          # Missing Quote
"PLEASE TELL QUOTE",
```

But there is no comma after the second one, so python is interpreting this by concatenating the two strings together and functionally reads this instead:

```
"PLEASE TELL ME A QUOTE",
"PLEASE TELL ME QUOTEPLEASE TELL QUOTE",
```